# How to calculate a month after a date Node.js

Tags: javascript, nestjs

I have this current date and I want to calculate a new date but one month after the current one and one year later, Node.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in date functions to set the month and the year.

```js
const currentDate = new Date();
console.log("before:", currentDate);

currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth() + 1);
currentDate.setFullYear(currentDate.getFullYear() + 1);

console.log("after:", currentDate);
```